# Return parent workbook range of particular sheet

Tags: vba, excel

using vlookup function one workbook to another workbook, this code `" & Rg.Parent.Parent.Name & "!" & Rg.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)` return the range from first sheet of the wb2, eventhough have set the rage (Rg) from third sheet of wb2 `Set Rg = wb2.Sheets(3).Range("A3:Z10000")` .. why the rage (Rg) not returning of the third sheet of wb2 and how to return the rage of specific sheet of wb2 ?

```
Sub Vlkuprangcall()
Dim strColumn As String
Dim Rg As Range
Dim wb2 As Workbook

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ashokkumar.d\Desktop\Test\IC Raphael\Janalakshmi\MIS\MIS.xlsx")
Set Rg = wb2.Sheets(3).Range("A3:Z10000")

Application.Workbooks(2).Activate
With ActiveSheet
    a = ActiveCell.Column
    lastrow = 100
    strColumn = Split(ActiveCell.Address, "$")(1)
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC[-15]," & Rg.Parent.Parent.Name & "!" & Rg.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",6,False)"
    ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, Range(strColumn & lastrow))

end Sub
```

Comment: after trying to indent your code a little, you are missing a `End With` to your `With ActiveSheet` statement, besides other issues in your code

Comment: Note you misspelt the variable strColumn (which I fixed here above). I strongly recommend `Option Explicit` at top of your code - it spots variable typos as "Forces explicit declaration of all variables"

Comment: Just a helpful note  - note its "Range" not "rage" in your question. Beware of the Angry Sheets!

Comment: @ShaiRado i have bit of doubt, if assign the column index number to the variable of wb2 like `d=6` how to call in vlookup `"=vlookup(RC[-15]," & Rg.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, xlExternal) & ",d,False)"` is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Address` with the 4th parameter being `xlExternal`, it will add the `Worksheet` object's name, and also the `Workbook` object's name.

So your `FormulaR1C1` line should be:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC[-15]," & Rg.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, xlExternal) & ",6,False)"
```

***Note***: your should try to avoid using `Activate`, `ActiveSheet`, and `ActiveCell`, instead use fully qualified `Range` and `Cells` objects.

Comment: oh  now have activated into green

Comment: i have bit of doubt, if assign the column index number to the variable of wb2 like `d=6` how to call in vlookup `"=vlookup(RC[-15]," & Rg.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, xlExternal) & ",d,False)"` is it correct?

Comment: @Ashok sounds lke a good new Post. You should open a new post, add you lateset modifed code, and what you are trying to achieve, this will allow other users (ad myslef) helping you on this specific issue

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Address` is easier, but to address your question, `Rg.Parent` or `Rg.Worksheet` gets a reference to the work**sheet** containing the range. You used `Rg.Parent.Parent` which is a reference to the work**book**. You need both for the formula, assuming you are using a cross-workbook formula.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC[-15],'[" & Rg.Parent.Parent.Name & "]" & rg.Worksheet.Name & "'!" & Rg.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",6,False)"
```